# Group related constants in Python

Tags: python, enums, python-class

I'm looking for a pythonic way to define multiple related constants in a single file to be used in multiple modules. I came up with multiple options, but all of them have downsides.

#### Approach 1 - simple global constants

```py
# file resources/resource_ids.py

FOO_RESOURCE = 'foo'
BAR_RESOURCE = 'bar'
BAZ_RESOURCE = 'baz'
QUX_RESOURCE = 'qux'
```

```py
# file runtime/bar_handler.py

from resources.resource_ids import BAR_RESOURCE

# ...

def my_code():
  value = get_resource(BAR_RESOURCE)
```

This is simple and universal, but has a few downsides:

- `_RESOURCE` has to be appended to all constant names to provide context
- Inspecting the constant name in IDE will not display other constant values

#### Approach 2 - enum

```py
# file resources/resource_ids.py

from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class ResourceIds(Enum):
  foo = 'foo'
  bar = 'bar'
  baz = 'baz'
  qux = 'qux'
```

```
# file runtime/bar_handler.py

from resources.resource_ids import ResourceIds

# ...

def my_code():
  value = get_resource(ResourceIds.bar.value)
```

This solves the problems of the first approach, but the downside of this solution is the need of using `.value` in order to get the string representation (assuming we need the string value and not just a consistent enum value). Failure to append `.value` can result in hard to debug issues in runtime.

#### Approach 3 - class variables

```py
# file resources/resource_ids.py

class ResourceIds:
  foo = 'foo'
  bar = 'bar'
  baz = 'baz'
  qux = 'qux'
```

```
# file runtime/bar_handler.py

from resources.resource_ids import ResourceIds

# ...

def my_code():
  value = get_resource(ResourceIds.bar)
```

This approach is my favorite, but it may be misinterpreted - classes are made to be instantiated. And while code correctness wouldn't suffer from using an instance of the class instead of the class itself, I would like to avoid this waste.

Another disadvantage of this approach that the values are not actually constant. Any code client can potentially change them.

Is it possible to prevent a class from being instantiated? Am I missing some idiomatic way of grouping closely related constants?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Enum` and mix in `str`:

```
@unique
class ResourceIds(str, Enum):
    foo = 'foo'
    bar = 'bar'
    baz = 'baz'
    qux = 'qux'
```

Then you won't need to compare against `.value`:

```
>>> ResourceIds.foo == 'foo'
True
```

And you still get good debugging info:

```
>>> ResourceIds.foo
<ResourceIds.foo: 'foo'>

>>> list(ResourceIds.foo.__class__)
[
 <ResourceIds.foo: 'foo'>,
 <ResourceIds.bar: 'bar'>,
 <ResourceIds.baz: 'baz'>,
 <ResourceIds.qux: 'qux'>,
]
```

Comment: Nice! And it even works with dictionaries: 
`d = {ResourceIds.foo: 'foo_value'}
print(d['foo'])  # prints "foo_value"
`

Answer (score 1):

A few ways you can do this, I don't really like using enum in python because you dont *really* need them IMO ;)

This is how most packages out there do it AFAIK:

```
# module_name.py
CSV = 'csv'
JSON = 'json'

def save(path, format=CSV):
    # do some thing with format
    ...

# other_module.py
import module_name

module_name.save('my_path', fomat=module_name.CSV)
```

another way is like this:

```
# module_name.py
options = {
    'csv': some_csv_processing_function
    'json': some_json_processing_function
}

def save(path, format=options.['csv']:
    # do some thing with format
    ...

# other_module.py
import module_name

module_name.save('my_path', fomat=module_name.options['csv'])
```

(kinda unrelated) You can also make your dicts classes:

```
class DictClass:
    def __init__(self, dict_class):
        self.__dict__ = dict_class

options = DictClass({
    'csv': some_csv_processing_function
    'json': some_json_processing_function
})
```

now you can access your dictionary as an object like: `options.csv`

Comment: Good to know, thanks for providing the context! Do you think these packages use constants and not enums because they were developed back when enums were not a thing?